# jplayer wont pause streaming audio

Tags: audio, streaming, jplayer

I am trying to create a jplayer streaming audio player but have run into an issue where the player wont "pause" the audio. The player will stop and start the audio, but I am looking to make it pause the audio in the current location of the stream and resume the audio when play is pressed again.

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

var stream = {
    title: "",
    mp3:""
},
ready = false;

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        ready = true;
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
    },
    pause: function() {
        $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");
    },
    error: function(event) {
        if(ready && event.jPlayer.error.type ===                                      

$.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {
            // Setup the media stream again and play it.
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
        }
    },
    swfPath: "dist/jplayer",
    supplied: "mp3",
    preload: "none",
    wmode: "window",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    keyEnabled: true
});

});
//]]>
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio" role="application" aria-label="media player">
<div class="jp-type-single">
    <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">

        </div>
        <div class="jp-controls-holder">
            <div class="auto-style1">
            <form>
<input  name="image" type="image" src="play100.png" class="jp-play"  tabindex="0" <?=$dis?>
<input  name="image" type="image" src="pause100.png" class="jp-pause" <?=$dis?>

<input  name="image" type="image" src="stop100.png" class="jp-stop" <?=$dis?>

</form>


            </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jp-no-solution">

    </div>
</div>
```